# How to create Solidity bytes[] input argument in Go for Ethereum contract call

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, golang

I have a simple multicall contract in Solidity which has the following function:

```
function multiCall (address[] calldata targets,bytes[] calldata data) external view returns(Return[] memory returnData)
```

What I'd like to achieve is to call this function from Golang with the go-ethereum package. So far I could construct an array with address type, but couldn't for the `bytes[] calldata data`.

```
signature := "0x0902f1ac" // function modifier string
addressList := make([]common.Address, 0)
addressList = []common.Address{common.HexToAddress("0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16")}
sigs := make([]byte, 0)
sigs = []byte{signature} // warning: cannot use signature (variable of type string) as byte value in array or slice 

data, err := contractABI.Pack("multiCall", addressList, sigs )

callMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{
    To:   &contractAddress,
    Data: data, 
}
```

My question is, how should I correctly prepare the `sigs` slice and its content to use it as an input argument for my Solidity functions `bytes[] calldata data` input?

Answer (score 0):

With go, the process of generating a signature should return bytes.

Example;

```
sig, err := MySigner.SignTypedData(data)
```

sig will be of type byte. In your example you are using an hexadecimal string.

It should not be converted to string if it's from go code, otherwise it has to be converted from hex to bytes.

See

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404326/how-to-transfer-hex-strings-to-byte-directly-in-go